# Powershell format date after .AddDays() method

Tags: powershell

I can't find a way to format a date after using `.AddDays()`

**CODE**

```
[datetime] $searchDate = '2020-01-10'
$searchDate = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f $searchDate.AddDays(1)
```

returns "Saturday, January 11, 2020 12:00:00 AM" while I'm looking for 2020-01-11

Comment: Be careful with date formats. Depending on your locale, `01-10-2020` might be 1st of October or 10th of January. Consider using the only true date format, `yyyy-mm-dd` instead.

Comment: @vonPryz Noted but it still doesn't solve the returning format issue

Comment: You declared `$searchDate` to be a `DateTime` so that's what it will always be; formatting has no effect and you'll always get the shell's default format. Use a new variable that can take a string (or just leave off the explicit type and use `[datetime] '2020-01-10'`).

Comment: @vonPryz: A `[datetime]` _cast_ always uses the _invariant_ culture, so the `01` in `[datetime] '01-10-2020'` is _always_ the _month_ (but you can use the format `2020-01-10` to avoid confusion). The ambiguity - unexpectedly - only arises if you pass a string to a `[datetime]`-typed _cmdlet_ parameter, where the _current_ culture matters; note that _scripts and functions_ are _not_ affected; they act like casts - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65095705/45375).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

```
# NOTE: [datetime] must be on the RHS if you want to assign a different type later.
$searchDate = [datetime] '2020-01-10'
$searchDate = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f $searchDate.AddDays(1)
```

Of course, you can combine that into a single assignment:

```
$searchDate = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f ([datetime] '2020-01-10').AddDays(1)
```

Or, via `Get-Date`:

```
$searchDate = Get-Date ([datetime] '2020-01-10').AddDays(1) -Format yyyy-MM-dd
```

---

Your [own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65097628/45375) simply *bypasses* the conceptual problem with your code, which [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) describes well in a comment on the question.

> `[datetime] $searchDate = '2020-01-10'`

**By placing the cast (`[datetime]`) to the *left* of the variable (`$searchDate`) in your assignment, you *type-constrain* it.**

This means that **any values assigned *later* are *invariably and implicitly coerced* (converted) to the specified type** (`[datetime]`, in this case).

Therefore, you mustn't use the same variable to assign your *string* representation of a date, obtained with the `-f` operator, as that string representation is automatically reconverted to `[datetime]`.
That is, after executing
`$searchDate = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f $searchDate.AddDays(1)`, `$searchData` again contains a `[datetime]` instance, not the string of interest.

Another solution is to simply assign to a *different* variable, one that either isn't type-constrained or is constrained to `[string]`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with `Get-Date $searchDate -Format yyyy-MM-dd`